# Quasi polynomial algorithm for NP complete problem

Tags: lo.logic, computational-complexity, np

I know that quasi polynomial algorithm is neither polynomial nor exponential. But I want to know if we find such algorithm for NP complete problem, will it be of any use? Or is there such algorithm exists already?

I want to know why it becomes impossible to solve NP complete problems on regular machine. Is it because it will take huge time to solve? (Maybe in years) Or just because it's taking exponential time?
So if we find quasi polynomial algorithm, then also it will take years to solve NP complete problem or will it take less time and have practical applications in real life even it's not polynomial time?
Also does a quasi polynomial algorithm imply that P=NP?

Comment: It is expected that NP-complete problems have no subexponential-time algorithms. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_time_hypothesis .

Comment: I think this is a valid question for this forum (although maybe more suited to [CS-SE](https://cs.stackexchange.com/) or [CSTheory-SE](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/)), but the wording (“huge time to solve”, “maybe in years”) is clumsy at best. Interpreted as “what would be some consequences of a QP algorithm for an NP-complete problem?” (e.g. does the poly hierarchy collapse?), it is fine. Some relevant answers to similar questions have been provided [here](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/21571/17747) and [here](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/47653/17747).

Comment: But if quasi polynomial algorithm is found,  how will It affect cryptography and technology? Please explain me

Comment: I don't think this question is suitable for this site. It rather belongs to https://cs.stackexchange.com or https://math.stackexchange.com .

Comment: That depends much more on how practical the algorithm is more than anything else.  Constants may matter more.

Comment: Cross-posted: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/167293/755, https://mathoverflow.net/q/467758/37212. Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).

Comment: @Gro-Tsen, I appreciate your trying to help the poster.  However, if you're going to suggest another site, in the future I encourage you to let them know to avoid cross-posting -- you can suggest they delete the copy here before posting elsewhere, and make sure to incorporate all the feedback they got elsewhere.  By the way, please make sure you are familiar with the standards on the sites you suggest before suggesting another site.  This is not suitable for CS Theory.   I know you want to help.  At the same time, it won't help anyone to have unsuitable questions pushed to other sites.